# How to order my array data by ascending last name?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to sort data by its last name. My array is:

```
$arr = array(
    [0] => adm gil,
    [1] => art bull,
    [2] => ricky admire,
)
```

I need to sort this array by ascending order based on its last name like:

```
$arr = array(
    [0] => ricky admire,
    [1] => art bull,
    [2] => adm gil,
)
```

Can you help me to solve this in PHP? I tried while 1st `explode` and then asc but did not get success.

Comment: Try usort() to sort by last name.

Comment: @nice_dev but for usort() i need to make function

Answer (score 1):

use `usort`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Assuming that there will always be a space in the name string,
you can write custom sort like so.

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(explode(' ', $a)[1], explode(' ', $b)[1]);
});

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this exercise better is you can create an associative array and take the last name as a key in the array.
example:-

```
    $arr = array('gil' => 'adm gil','bull' => 'art bull','admire' => 'ricky admire');
    ksort($arr);
    print_r($arr);
```

The output is:-
Array
(
[admire] => ricky admire
[bull] => art bull
[gil] => adm gil
)

Comment: You might also want to show how to make last names as keys programmatically.

Comment: `code` $name = 'adm gil';
$id = substr($name, strrpos($name, ' ') + 1);
echo $id; `code`

Comment: $name = 'adm gil';
$id = substr($name, strrpos($name, ' ') + 1);
echo $id;

Comment: Answered by anurat chapanond  failed with below array.
`code` $arr1 = array('adm gil','art bull','ricky singh admire'); `code`
already tested that's why I suggest you above solution

Comment: I am not the guy who asked the question.